# Run parallel tasks in a long running application

Tags: java, parallel-processing, threadpool, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I am building a long running application, which is modeled as a service based on service oriented architecture. Call this as 'serviceA'. It has an activity to perform, call 'activityA', whenever an API call is made to it.

activityA has an activity handler that has to perform 'n' tasks in parallel after which it consolidates and returns result to the client who called the serviceA API.

I am planning to use the ExecutorService to achieve this parallelism.

There are 2 ways to go ahead with this:

1. Create ExecutorService in a singleton scope, and have it as an attribute of the activity handler. Thus this same ExecutorService object is available throughout the lifetime of the service. When a new request comes, handler uses this ExecutorService object to submit parallel tasks. Then wait on the Future objects for certain timeout time. After all the parallel tasks complete, consolidate and return the activityA response.
2. Create new ExecutorService object everytime a request to activityA is received, in the activity handler. Submit the parallel tasks to this object, wait for the Future results for certain timeout time, consolidate the results, call shutdown on the ExecutorService object, and return the activityA API response.

Thus,

1. Which of the 2 above approaches should be followed? Major difference b/w the 2 is the lifetime of the ExecutorService object.
2. The service is supposed to be called with a volume of ~15k transactions per second, if this data helps with the decision making b/w the 2 approaches?
3. Advantage of 1st approach is that we will not have the overhead of creating and shutting down new ExecutorService objects, and threads. But, what happens when there is no Future result till the timeout time? Does the thread automatically shuts down? Is it available for any new request that will be coming to the ExecutorService thread pool? Or it will be in some waiting state, and eat up memory - in which case we manually need to do something (and what)?
4. Also, Timeout time while we call future.get() is from the time we make this get call or from the time we submitted the task to the executor service?

Please also let me know if any of the 2 way is the obvious approach to this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I think, it may help you http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html RxJava is one of the best solution for perform parallel task, and of course it's better then reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks Ivan for the suggestion! Will possibly look into it. But as for now I want to stick with the ExecutorService because of less turnaround time for the project.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first way looks like the obvious and correct way to solve this problem, especially with the given amount of transactions. You certainly don't want to restart threads.
2. `Future.get` timeout doesn't affect the executing thread. It will continue to run the task until it is either completed or throws an exception. Until then, it won't be accepting new tasks (but other threads in the same executor will). In this case you may want to cancel it explicitly by invoking `Future.cancel` to free the thread for new tasks. This requires the task itself to respond properly to interrupt (instead of looping forever, for example, or waiting blocked on I/O). However, this would be the same for *any* threading approach since interruption is the only safe way to terminate a thread anyway. To mitigate this issue you could use a dynamic pool of threads with maximum number of running threads more than `n`. This will allow to process new tasks while the stuck tasks are in process of termination.
3. It's from the time you call it.